# Using a list in a string.format in Python 2.7?

Tags: python

Let's assume I have a explicitly defined list, with a known number of (numeric) elements, say `aa=[1,2,3,4,5]` - and I'd like to print these in a specific string. I'm aware I can do this:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:49:48) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> aa=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> print "%dx%d+%d+%dx%d"%tuple(aa)
1x2+3+4x5
```

... but I'm not very fond of how the format string `"%dx%d+%d+%dx%d"` looks like, and I'd much rather use `string.format` kind of specifiers. Then, I'm aware I can use this:

```
>>> print "{}x{}+{}+{}x{}".format(aa[0], aa[1], aa[2], aa[3], aa[4])
1x2+3+4x5
```

... but I find writing all the arguments for `string.format` expanded as `aa[0], aa[1], aa[2], aa[3], aa[4]` a bit overkill, since in this case, I explicitly know I have enough `{}` specifiers for all the elements of the array/list, so I'd much rather just throw `aa` in there, as in:

```
>>> print "{}x{}+{}+{}x{}".format(aa)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

... but unfortunately, that doesn't work.

So, what would be a way - if there is one -, to just refer to a list like `aa` in the argument of `string.format`, without having to specifically expand each of its elements as a separate argument?

Comment: `.format(*aa)`?

Comment: you need `"{}x{}+{}+{}x{}".format(*aa)` to unpack the elements

Comment: Jeez, thanks guys - that is what I needed; if any of you wants to post an answer, I'll accept it; cheers! Duplicate is fine, too...

Comment: @jonrsharpe I found a better duplicate. Swapped yours in second position. hope you don't mind

Comment: @sdaau no need since it's a duplicate. Of course you can always upvote the answer(s) in the original question(s) :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm not that picky; I've no doubt there are plenty of others, too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe typical me: I don't like changing moderating actions without warning others first (unlike some guy I won't name who systematically reopens the dupes I'm closing just because _he_ answered). I admit that the linked question has an answer from mine :) but I had that in the clipboard when you beat me to close.